# WPF parse binding expression

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, binding

Is there any way of turning a string containing a binding expression into a Binding object?

A simple example would be `"{Binding Path}"`,

or:

`"{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=views:IPage}, Path=TensileTestChange}"`

The actual binding expression is stored in XML, which is a higher-level representation of a XAML document.

Comment: You could look into the [`Binding` constructor that takes a string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms597578.aspx)

Comment: Hi @Trustme-I'maDoctor, I've expanded with another example I need to implement

Comment: I have never actually used raw `Binding` before, so the best I can personally do is just refer you to the [`Binding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms617928.aspx) class, which holds all the properties you need - in fact it's the same binding that's used in XAML. I don't know if you can just pass it a predefined string somehow, or if you'd have to parse the string first (which would be counterproductive).

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately I already use the raw binding class. I was wondering in my question whether there was a ready made solution to parse a binding expression and return a Binding object

Comment: Maybe [XamlReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.markup.xamlreader.aspx) would be of help here then...?

Comment: Looks like it's the way to go!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are asking is to parse a `MarkupExtension`. I could not find WPF's implementation directly (it's contained somewhere in the `XamlReader.Parse` call chain).

After some googling, it seems there is no ready made solution available to do this. However, if you have some experience with writing parsers you could roll your own. The specification for parsing a MarkupExtension is given on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee200269.aspx).

As a workaround, you could fake a control where you put the binding on:

```
string myBindingExpression = "{Binding MyProperty}";

var test = "<TextBlock xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation\" Text=\"" 
    + myBindingExpression + "\" />";
var result = XamlReader.Parse(test) as TextBlock;
var bindingExpression = result.GetBindingExpression(TextBlock.TextProperty);

Binding binding = bindingExpression.ParentBinding
```

This creates a TextBlock with the binding as the Text property. It will give you the binding object with the properties set according to the binding expression.

You can then apply the binding wherever.

Remember though, for your more complex example with the xmlns prefix, you need to include the `xmlns:views="..."` in the fake `TextBlock`, otherwise it will not know what to do with the prefix.

Example: `<TextBlock xmlns:views="..." xmlns="..." Text="{Binding MyProperty}" />`

Comment: Thanks Bas, good to know it's called a MarkupExtension, I couldn't find the correct term for it! I'll keep in mind the comment about the xmlns as well, thanks!